# div displaying behind other content in form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a autocomplete field which when you type your area or county it autofills the data from a database.  All this works perfectly however when you start typing the box with the suggestions displays behind the main content div.

You can see an example of this by going to 
http://dev.exclusivecard.co.uk

if once there you type "Merseyside" into the field just left of the search button at the top of the page you will see a box appears but it appears behind the main content.  The code I'm using can be found here
       http://phppot.com/demo/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-country-example/

my css looks as follows...

```
 #list-box{ position:absolute;}
 #country-list{position:relative; float:left;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:190px; color:#262626;}
 #country-list li{padding: 10px; background:#FAFAFA;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;}
  #country-list li:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
  #demo-content table.tutorial-table {table-layout:auto;}
```

and the page

```
<div id="demo-content">
    <div class="frmSearch">
        <input class="form-control" name="search-box" id="search-box"  type="text" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['localArea'])){ echo $_COOKIE['localArea'];}?>" />
        <div id="list-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example link is not working.

Comment: which link.  Ive just tested them both and they seem fine

Comment: Ok my fault. Clear the cache did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if #list-box is the parent div, then you just need to give it a large z-index.

```
 #list-box{ position:absolute; z-index:9999}
```

Answer (score 1):

Play CSS z-index property order to each element to it appers in the order you need.